# Aggregate records in a stream based on time or end marker

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Consider the notion of an input stream of intertwined records representing a user interaction (for example a product purchase).  Imagine we receive records that indicate a user has placed a product in their shopping basket.  At some time later, they perform a check-out ... or ... abandon their cart.

I thus receive a stream of records such as:

- Transaction: 123, Added item A to basket
- Transaction: 123, Added item B to basket
- ...
- Transaction: 123, Checked out basket

My goal is to output from the pipeline the aggregate of the transaction.  For example, given the above, I want to output:

`Transaction 123, Items A, B, ... Sale completed`

or if no check-out occurs within 24 hours from the last event:

`Transaction 123, Items A, B, ... Sale abandoned`

... and this is where I'm stuck.  I feel that there is some way to think about this story from an Apache Beam pipeline perspective but I'm afraid I'm at a loss on where to begin.  I'm thinking that I somehow want to window the records by both transaction and termination and only emit a batch for processing when either an *end* of transaction record is received or some time interval has elapsed since the last record seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data based window markers have an inherent assumption on ordering of data which is not supported by Beam. In the above schenario, it is assumed that checkout event will come after all the add to the cart events.

However to solve this problem in a crude way you can use [State](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/state/BagState.java) along with Session window to express this in a crude way.

PCollection-RawEvents: Read raw events

PCollection-1: PCollection-RawEvents -> Apply 24 hour `SessionWindow` to all events.

PCollection-Checkout: PCollection-1 -> Push all the elements for a key in `BagState`. Read back the state and publish the event `Transaction 123, Items A, B, ... Sale completed` when you get checkout event  `Transaction: 123, Checked out basket`.

PCollection-Abandon: PCollection-1 -> GroupByKey -> Publish `Transaction 123, Items A, B, ... Sale abandoned` if `Transaction: 123, Checked out basket` is not present.

PCollection-Unified: Flatten (PCollection-Checkout, PCollection-Abandon)

Comment: Thank you for this.  The whole state thing was unknown to me ... starting to study now.  For those who may need to follow ... it appears that this is a good write-up ... https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html

Comment: ... and another good article ... https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html

Comment: It has taken me a couple of days to even begin to comprehend your answer.  The whole state stuff was 100% new to me.  However as I now read your answer (without having coded it up yet) ... all I can say is WOW ... that is pretty darn smart.  I'm in admiration of your comprehension of Beam to be able to design such flows.